# Using Facebook SDK in Yii

Tags: yii, facebook-php-sdk

Anyone has any experience on use Facebook SDK in YII 1? I've read a lot of links but I think that the problem is on the way I'm trying to autoload the Facebook SDK.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more specific about the problem?

I personally have some experiences with HybridAuth  (http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/). It provides a easy implemenation for various social API's and it also has a Yii extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hoauth/

Comment: Finally I solved my problems using the Facebook sdk. Now I'm with twitter. I'll check this extension. Thanks for your answer.